# svn diff returns E175009 after ~25 minutes

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I'm attempting to map an SVN repo into Fisheye/Crucible for use with the code reviews feature. I'm running into issues with one of the commands Fisheye runs, but the source of the trouble seems to originate with the SVN server. VisualSVN Server 3.6.1, 64-bit is being used.

```
svn diff --summarize -r 6427:6428 http://file2/svn/REPO/@6428
```

I tested the same command locally on the SVN server, but after about 25 minutes the stream of text was interrupted with

```
svn: E175009: The XML response contains invalid XML
svn: E130003: Malformed XML: no element found
```

Examples of this error I've found seem to indicate that the URL was improperly entered in the command, but this doesn't seem applicable to my case as about 110MB of data come down initially.

Monitoring the Event Viewer while the command runs generates 3 errors, but doesn't result in the command stopping it's execution. Subsequent re-runs result in the same 3 errors each time.

```
Provider encountered an error while streaming a REPORT response.  [500, #0]
A failure occurred while driving the update report editor  [500, #106]
Unknown error  [500, #106]
```

SVN Verify against the repo reported no issues.

As a workaround, I can set Fisheye to start indexing after the problem revision, but this results in files last modified before that revision lacking the diff data in a review, so it is not ideal.

**Update 1**
The revisions in question seem to be surrounding a redesign of how the repo was layed out, and I've read that this can cause issues when using a 3rd party tool. I also noted there was a bug in SVN prior to 1.9.5 which would allow invalid-in-xml characters, so I'm trying some version downgrades to see if that helps.

**Update 2**
These seem to be caused by a particular branch that was created when doing the above mentioned redesign of the repo layout. Some more research suggests I could use svndumpfilter to remove undesirable items. I didn't find anything regarding how to remove a branch, just particular files.
I also attempted to export and import the repo to a new installation, but that did not resolve the issue.

Generally the administration of SVN has been easy enough, but I'm at a loss for how to resolve this issue. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to avoid this error by configuring repository access over the svn:// protocol. While this isn't directly supported by VisualSVN, the required svnserve.exe was present and was configured as a new service pointing to a copy of the repo.

```
sc create svncustom binpath= "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service -r F:\RepositoriesCopy" displayname= "Subversion Workaround Server" depend= Tcpip start= auto
```

This doesn't appear to be a secure solution, but it removes the error I was experiencing which was a hard block.